# Translate CURL into Python -- For Twitter API

Tags: python, api, twitter

I am looking to pull Twitter Engagement Metrics (Impressions, Favorites, etc.) via Python 'requests'. I was able to get authorized through the code below:

```
client_key = '*{Client Key}*'
client_secret = '*{Client Secret}*' 

import base64

key_secret = '{}:{}'.format(client_key,client_secret).encode('ascii')
b64_encoded_key = base64.b64encode(key_secret)
b64_encoded_key = b64_encoded_key.decode('ascii')

import requests

base_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/'
auth_url = '{}oauth2/token'.format(base_url)

auth_headers = {
    'Authorization':'Basic {}'.format(b64_encoded_key),
    'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
}

auth_data = {
    'grant_type':'client_credentials'
}

auth_resp = requests.post(auth_url, headers = auth_headers, data=auth_data)
```

However, I don't know how to translate the CURL below into Python code:

```
curl --request POST 
  --url https://data-api.twitter.com/insights/engagement/totals 
  --header 'accept-encoding: gzip' 
  --header 'authorization: Bearer ' 
  --header 'content-type: application/json' 
  --data '{
                "tweet_ids": [
                    "1070059276213702656","1021817816134156288","1067094924124872705"
                ],
                "engagement_types": [
                    "favorites","retweets","replies","video_views"
                ],
                "groupings": {
                    "perTweetMetricsUnowned": {
                        "group_by": [
                            "tweet.id",
                            "engagement.type"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            } 
  --verbose 
  --compressed
```

Twitter API reference: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/metrics/get-tweet-engagement/api-reference/post-insights-engagement#Historical

Does anyone have a solution? Thanks in advance!

Most people would use Tweepy to stream Twitter data. However, what I was looking for is to observe the Tweet delivery throughout the time and thus I have to use the 'https://data-api.twitter.com/insights/engagement/' endpoint, which Tweepy does not cover.

Comment: One thing to note is that you need to have access to the Engagement API for this to work - this is a paid API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should just be able to create data and header dictionaries and post away:

```py
headers = {
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip',
    'authorization': 'Bearer',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
}
data = {
    "tweet_ids": [
        "1070059276213702656","1021817816134156288","1067094924124872705"
    ],
    "engagement_types": [
        "favorites","retweets","replies","video_views"
    ],
    "groupings": {
        "perTweetMetricsUnowned": {
            "group_by": [
                "tweet.id",
                "engagement.type"
            ]
        }
    }
}
req = requests.post(
    "https://data-api.twitter.com/insights/engagement/totals",
    headers=headers,
    data=data
)
```

Comment: Just noticed this is using the exact same method that the authentication is in your authentication snippet!

Comment: Thanks for the help! I realized this API endpoint is a premium version that needs to be paid for.